# Why is this mapping a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, jacobian, diffeomorphism

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $$\varphi_{xx}\varphi_{yy} - \varphi_{xy}^2 = 1$$.

Then define the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (\xi, \eta)$ by:
$$
\xi(x,y) = x+\varphi_x(x,y)\:, \: \eta(x,y) = y+\varphi_y(x,y)
$$
It is claimed that this mapping is a diffeomorphism. I have a proof which involves some inequalities [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969907?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=%22nitsche%22&searchText=bernstein&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoAdvancedSearch%3Fq0%3D%2522nitsche%2522%26amp%3Bf0%3Dau%26amp%3Bc1%3DAND%26amp%3Bq1%3Dbernstein%26amp%3Bf1%3Dall%26amp%3Bc2%3DAND%26amp%3Bq2%3D%26amp%3Bf2%3Dall%26amp%3Bc3%3DAND%26amp%3Bq3%3D%26amp%3Bf3%3Dall%26amp%3Bc4%3DAND%26amp%3Bq4%3D%26amp%3Bf4%3Dall%26amp%3Bc5%3DAND%26amp%3Bq5%3D%26amp%3Bf5%3Dall%26amp%3Bc6%3DAND%26amp%3Bq6%3D%26amp%3Bf6%3Dall%26amp%3Bacc%3Doff%26amp%3Bla%3D%26amp%3Bsd%3D%26amp%3Bed%3D%26amp%3Bpt%3D%26amp%3Bisbn%3D%26amp%3Bgroup%3Dnone&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_SYC-5144%2Fcontrol&refreqid=search%3Aab64bc0872f36d6962f8ce4b6b98f867&seq=1) but I would like to show this in a more "direct" way. I have calculated the Jacobian as:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\xi_x & \xi_y \\
\eta_x & \eta_y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\varphi_{xx} & \varphi_{xy} \\
\varphi_{xy} & 1+\varphi_{yy}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This has the determinant $$\det(J) = 1+\varphi_{xx} + \varphi_{yy} + \varphi_{xx}\varphi_{yy} - \varphi_{xy}^2$$
Using the hypothesis this is $\det(J) = 2+\varphi_{xx} + \varphi_{yy}$.

**What I think:** I cannot prove that the above is definitely not equal to $0$, other than assuming from the beginning that $\varphi_{xx}, \varphi_{yy} \geq 0$. EDIT: This is simply achieved by changing the sign of $\varphi$ in case it so happens that $\varphi_{xx}, \varphi_{yy} < 0$ (as suggested in [this paper](https://maths.anu.edu.au/files/CMAProcVol34P2-Athanassenas.pdf)).

Comment: At best what you're discussing here is whether the mapping is a *local* diffeomorphism (as implied by the Inverse Function Theorem). Otherwise you must do serious justifications that the map is a bijection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that $J$ has $\det(J) = \operatorname{tr}(J)$. The eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of $J$ must satisfy $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. If ever one is zero, the other must be as well. So if $J$ is singular, it must be the zero matrix.

If $J$ is the zero matrix, then $\varphi_{xx} = \varphi_{yy} = -1$ and $\varphi_{xy} = 0$. By integrating the latter equation we have that $\varphi(x,y) = u(x) + v(y)$. Integrating $u$ with respect to $x$ and $v$ with respect to $y$,
$$ \varphi(x,y) = cx + dy + e - \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) $$

Without additional hypotheses on $\varphi$, looks like $\varphi(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$ is a counterexample to the claim that $(x,y) \mapsto (x + \varphi_x, y + \varphi_y)$ is a local diffeomorphism.

More generally, this actually shows $(x,y)\mapsto (x+\varphi_x+y+\varphi_y)$ is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $\varphi$ is not of the form $-(x^2 + y^2)/2 + \mbox{linear}$.

If we require that $\varphi$ is convex, this rules out the only class of functions that makes $J$ singular, so we get that $(x,y)\mapsto (x+\varphi_x, y+\varphi_y)$ is a local diffeomorphism. I think the paper you linked needs to make convexity a hypothesis, as flipping the sign of $\varphi$ is clearly not WLOG.

Comment: Isn't $\varphi$ convex anyway? Since we are supposing $\varphi_{xx}\varphi_{yy} + \varphi_{xy}^2 = 1$. This is a positive Hessian which is equivalent to $\varphi$ being convex no?

Comment: The pde holding does not imply a positive Hessian. For example the equation holds for $\varphi(x,y) = -(x^2 + y^2)/2$ which certainly does not have a positive Hessian.

Comment: Im sorry but is the Hessian not the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \varphi_{xx} & \varphi_{xy} \\ \varphi_{xy} & \varphi_{yy} \end{bmatrix}$? Thus my impression is that the determinant of this matrix is exactly the PDE given.

Comment: Yes, that's the Hessian. My point is that $\det(M) > 0$ does not mean $M$ is a positive matrix. So if $\varphi(x,y) = -(x^2 + y^2)/2$, then $\operatorname{Hess}(\varphi) = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake. I was thinking that a positive determinant implied that the matrix is positive semidefinite. Now I see it is in fact the other way around (for symmetric matrices). Thanks!